# This code parses a json-format URL to create a typical news feed

Tags: json, swift, xml, xcode

I got this from the codingwithchris.com Xcode tutorial, which is pretty good. I tried to substitute the URL of my xml-formatted URL in place of Chris's json-formatted newsapi.org URL. 
As expected I got "Error parsing the json". Grateful for any quick tips.

```
let stringUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=8c4d5faa662f4dce849d17d89e86ca14"
let url = URL(string: stringUrl)
guard url != nil else {
    print("Couldn't create url object")
    return
}
let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
  if error == nil && data != nil {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      do {
          let articleService = try decoder.decode(ArticleService.self, from: data!)
          if articleService.articles == nil {
              return
          }
          let articles = articleService.articles!
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.delegate?.articlesRetrieved(articles)
           } // end DispatchQueue.main.sync
       } end do
       catch {
           print("Error parsing the json")
       } // End catch

  } // End if

} // End dataTask

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for ArticleService? I tried using a simple structure and it worked.

Comment: In addition to adding the code for ArticleService you can get the error variable form the catch block and print it for more insight:

`
       catch let e {
           print("Error parsing the json: \(e)")
       } // End catch
`

Comment: You haven't said what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do set answer as the correct answer if you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are using an incorrect structure for decoding the json. Here is what you need.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title, description, url, urlToImage: String
    let publishedAt: String
    let content: String?
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}
```